# python import a non standard library

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Hi I downloaded a cool github to run in jupyter notebook. 
however I need to import this "non standard library" by the author

1. downloaded the files
2. I put the file in the same folder, made sure that my notebook is pointing there.
3. type "import indicators" in the notebook
   (by the way its a file called indicators.py in https://github.com/voice32/stock_market_indicators/)

and I get this error

> *Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>     File "", line 5, in 
>       import indicators
>     File "C:\Users\ney12\Google Drive\1) Financial Mastery\3) paper assets, trading, Other assets\forex\Van tharp Forex trading system\Ney study of van tharp forex trading system\Forex-initial-analysis\indicators.py", line 235
>       val_last = val
>                     ^
>   TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation*

just in case I open the command line and type "pip install indicators.py"
but I get an error:

> *"  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement indicators.py (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for indicators.py"*

**help please!**

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the stacktrace:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

This happens when someone uses tabs and spaces interchangeably for indentation in a script. Quite frustrating

I'd suggest opening that file in the text editor of your choice and doing a bulk find-and-replace of tabs and replace with spaces. You can do that with the `\t` char in the find bar (note the escape slash), and then either `\s{4}` (if regex is enabled) or just hit space 4 times in the replace field. Save it, then re-import it with a fresh python shell

Comment: Or you can reindent the entire directory by using `autopep8 package_dir --recursive --select=E101,E121 --in-place`. You need to install `autopep8` using pip!

Comment: @bro-grammer that's really cool, never knew you could do that

Answer (score 2):

Run **autopep8**  on the module you downloaded.

i.e.

```
pip install autopep8
autopep8 --in-place <File.py>
```

You now should be good to go